# How to get ID of the newly created folder from SPD 2010 workflow as an Integer?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am not sure if this is a new feature / bug or if it was always there. Microsoft support couldn't explained this behaviour eventually saying it was beyond their support boundary (SharePoint Online).

I create a new folder (content-type-ID = Folder) in a document library using Create New Item activity.

At this point, I can use Created variable returned by the activity to reference the newly created item in an Update Item activity. All good. However if I want to store this new ID for future use things gets complicated. My intuition is to put Created into an Integer variable and store in a list field. But strangely, this integer conversion returns a different value from the actual ID of the newly created item.

If I just create one folder and convert its created output to integer I end up with actual ID minus one, however if I create 5 folders in quick succession, the value I get after integer conversion is actual ID - 5.

Is there a reliable way to get the actual ID of the new item into an integer variable ?

EDIT: Also, interestingly, folders created by SDP 2010 workflows have final IDs increasing by two. So a single workflow, creating a single folder. If I run it twice I get IDs 10 and 12 (while 9 and 11 is returned if a convert create variable to integer). MS explained this as a "hidden folder" being created.

No such issue with 2013 workflows, GUID is returned, and I can get actual ID by referencing the item using its GUID. And it gets increased by one every time, not two.

Comment: I needed to use 2010 workflows as item permissions are to be replaced shortly after creating the folder and later in the life cycle of the item. Solution I found, although not very elegant is to create the new folder using a 2013 workflow, retrieve ID using GUID and store it in the parent record (in another list). Then this workflow starts another 2010 workflow to set the permissions.